# Why won't this font change size?

Tags: java, fonts

I'm making a wordpad program and have tried to create a JComboBox to  change font size. It runs/compiles and shows my options, but when I click on an index the font size won't change. This is the only method that modifies font size, any suggestions to make it work?

```
 fontsize.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==0)
                            {
                                txt.setFont(txt.getFont().deriveFont(10));
                                txt.setLineWrap(true);
                            }

                            else if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==1){
                                Font fontss = txt.getFont();
                                Font biggerFont = fontss.deriveFont(10);
                                txt.setFont(biggerFont);
                                txt.setLineWrap(true);
                        }
                            else if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==2){
                                Font fontss = txt.getFont();
                                Font biggerFont = fontss.deriveFont(10);
                                txt.setFont(biggerFont);
                                txt.setLineWrap(true);
                    }
                            else if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==3){
                                Font fontss = txt.getFont();
                                Font biggerFont = fontss.deriveFont(10);
                                txt.setFont(biggerFont);
                                txt.setLineWrap(true);
                    }
                            else{}
                        }
                    }
                    );
```

Comment: You don't seem to be changing the number in `fontss.deriveFont(10);`

Answer (score 1):

> Why won't this font change size?

Because you didn't change the size at all.

You may want to have a look at the Java API for Font and see what `deriveFont(int)` actually means.

What you are supposed to place in the parameter list for `deriveFont(int style)` is the ***font style***, not the ***font size***. That is why are not able to change your font size.

> **public Font deriveFont(int style)**
>
> Creates a new Font object by replicating the current Font object and applying a new style to it.
>
> Parameters: style - *the style for the new Font*

If you want to change the font size from your current font, you can do this:

```
Font currFont = txt.getFont();
int newSize = 20;
txt.setFont(new Font(currFont.getName(), currFont.getStyle(), newSize));
```

Comment: There is an error when typing txt.setFont(your code), as JComboBox.setFont only can accept one parameter which is the font to set, not a constructor for a font for some reason. But with your help I was able to restructure my idea and make the program work!! Thanks again for answering!! Attached is my idea.

Comment: @BobbyC.Robillard My bad, I missed out `new Font()` in my codes. It is edited now. If it helps, you may consider accepting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the deriveFont method that takes a float as argument, this one will create a new Font with the same parameters but a new size.

```
Font biggerFont = fontss.deriveFont((float)10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `fontss.deriveFont(10);` is always 10.  Instead of hardcoding a number as is done in this case, probably a copy-and-paste error, it might be beneficial to use a map to associate index with font size and use the index (as key) to access the font or font size.

Comment: Yes it was a typo, but even changed it doesn't work. I'm confused by what you mean by a map?

Comment: Java provides lots of collection classes that allow you to use the data structures that are most relevant for storing data based on how to intend for your program to use the data.  [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is an example of such a collection class. See my answer below on how I would use a HashMap to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of the code above. JTextArea.setFont can only take one parameter which is a font, you have to create a new font with the JTextArea's current font and then set sai font as the parameter for

```
JTextArea.setFont(myFont);

        fontsize.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {Font currFont = txt.getFont();
                        if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==0)
                        {
                            int newSize = 10;
                            Font myIdea = new Font(currFont.getFontName(),currFont.getStyle(),newSize);
                            txt.setFont(myIdea);
                            txt.setLineWrap(true);
                        }

                        else if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==1){
                            int newSize = 12;
                            Font myIdea = new Font(currFont.getFontName(),currFont.getStyle(),newSize);
                            txt.setFont(myIdea);
                            txt.setLineWrap(true);
                    }
                        else if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==2){

                            int newSize = 14;
                            Font myIdea = new Font(currFont.getFontName(),currFont.getStyle(),newSize);
                            txt.setFont(myIdea);
                            txt.setLineWrap(true);
                }
                        else if(fontsize.getSelectedIndex()==3){
                            int newSize = 16;
                            Font myIdea = new Font(currFont.getFontName(),currFont.getStyle(),newSize);
                            txt.setFont(myIdea);
                            txt.setLineWrap(true);
                }
                        else{}
                    }
                }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve this problem using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

`fontsize.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener(){
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> fontSizeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int max = 4;
        int minSize = 10;
        {
            for(int i = 0; i< max; i++) {
                int fontSize = newSize + (2 * i);
                fontSizeMap.put(i, fontSize);
            }
        }`

```
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        Font currFont = txt.getFont();
        int index = fontsize.getSelectedIndex();
        if(fontSizeMap.get(index) != null)
        {
            int newSize = fontSizeMap.get(index);
            Font myIdea = new Font(currFont.getFontName(),currFont.getStyle(),newSize);
            txt.setFont(myIdea);
            txt.setLineWrap(true);
        } else {
            // do nothing or handle this case differently.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You could move the for loop and the initialization code to its own method if you so desire.